VS Code always maximizes terminal when opening PowerShell script
When opening a directory in VS Code and clicking on a PowerShell script, the terminal is maximized instead of splitting the screen between the Editor and Terminal tab.
Can I somehow control this setting so that I always see the Editor and Terminal tab?
Current behavior

Desired behavior

VS Code information
Version: 1.94.2 (system setup)
Commit: 384ff7382de624fb94dbaf6da11977bba1ecd427
Date: 2024-10-09T16:08:44.566Z
Electron: 30.5.1
ElectronBuildId: 10262041
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
Node.js: 20.16.0
V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631

settings.json
{
    "github.copilot.advanced": {
    },
    "http.proxySupport": "on",
    "http.proxy": "http://my.company.com:1234",
    "workbench.panel.opensMaximized": "always",
    "window.restoreWindows": "none",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "dotnetAcquisitionExtension.enableTelemetry": false,
    "telemetry.telemetryLevel": "off",
    "files.associations": {
        "*.json5": "jsonc"
    }
}

Update 16.12.2024
After doing a "VS Code extension bisect", I nailed it down to the ms-vscode.powershell extension:


Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled command in the command palette)? If not, then do an extension bisect to figure out what extension is causing it.

@starball: thank you for this hint. Thx to the extension bisect, I was able to nail it down to the ms-vscode.powershell extension - I've updated the question with my findings. Now I will file an issue in the corresponding GitHub repo.

GitHub issue: https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/5116

It's probably because you have "workbench.panel.opensMaximized": "always", in your settings. Just delete that line.

Open the settings with CTRL-,, search for terminal default location and change that from editor to view.

It's already view and setting it to editor no longer displays the terminal anymore

Then please post your settings.json (remove all personal stuff beforehand)

I've added a new section to the question

Weird, I cannot reproduce that behaviour, even with your setiings. Did you try to empty your settings.json and start VS Code with --disable-extensions? and what about uninstall & reinstall? Seems like one of these rare bugs that haunt VS Code from time to time :(.

Lucky me  emptying settings.json has no effect on this particular issue. Running VS Code with --disable-extensions leads to opening no terminal at all when opening a PowerShell script - maybe because this is handled by the PowerShell extension?

Your screenshot suggests that you manually resized your terminal view to fill the entire client area of Visual Studio Code.
To undo that:

Hover your mouse pointer over the top edge of the view until the mouse pointer turns into a short arrow pointing straight down and the edge is highlighted in blue (see screenshot).

Then click and drag the blue line downward, as far as desired.




Upon restart of VS Code, the faulty behavior (maximized terminal) is back again
